# Kalidasa addressing Devi as "my daughter"

Tags: bhakti, stotra, kalidasa

In Syamala Dandakam (of Telugu Kalidasa movie at 3 min 22 secs) he refers to the Devi as *sanu_MatPutrike*.

[SyamalaDandakam](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X3w5omAMF98&list=RDMMX3w5omAMF98&start_radio=1)

Can he address a goddess that way in a Stotram ? Is it by the power bestowed on him by Her that made him say so.. or in some self identification of consciousness?

Answer (score 2):

Of course, he can address the Goddess this way. Kalidas's attitude is known as Vatsalya.

> "But in order to realize God, one must assume one of these attitudes:
> santa, dasya, sakhya, **vatsalya**, or madhur.
>
> "Santa, the serene attitude. The rishis of olden times had this
> attitude toward God. They did not desire any worldly enjoyment. It is
> like the single-minded devotion of a wife to her husband. She knows
> that her husband is the embodiment of beauty and love, a veritable
> Madan.
>
> "Dasya, the attitude of a servant toward his master. Hanuman had this
> attitude toward Rama. He felt the strength of a lion when he worked
> for Rama. A wife feels this mood also. She serves her husband with all
> her heart and soul. A mother also has a little of this attitude, as
> Yasoda had toward Krishna.
>
> "Sakhya, the attitude of friendship. Friends say to one another, 'Come
> here and sit near me.' Sridama and other friends sometimes fed Krishna
> with fruit, part of which they had already eaten, and sometimes
> climbed on His shoulders.
>
> **"Vatsalya, the attitude of a mother toward her child. This was
> Yasoda's attitude toward Krishna. The wife, too, has a little of this.
> She feeds her husband with her very life-blood, as it were. The mother
> feels happy only when the child has eaten to his heart's content.
> Yasoda would roam about with butter in her hand, in order to feed
> Krishna.**
>
> "Madhur, the attitude of a woman toward her paramour. Radha had this
> attitude toward Krishna. The wife also feels it for her husband. This
> attitude includes all the other four."

**The Gospel of Sri Ramakrishna, Chapter 4, Advice to Householders**

Comment: The Devi can address  a Bhaktha as " Madputra"  etc., but the Bhaktha cannot take liberty, by virtue of just now acquired Vathsalya,  to address Her as "MadPuthrike."

Comment: ""Vatsalya, the attitude of a mother toward her child." -- how can Kalidasa think himself to be the mother of the Goddess?

Comment: Yashoda was the foster mother of Krishna so obviously her attitude towards Krishna will be of Vatsalya but how can Kalidasa imagine himself to be the mother of Goddess?

Comment: Obviously Kalidas thought of himself as the FATHER of the Goddess.

Comment: Ramakrishna's expression 'attitude of mother towards her child' is an analogy. One shouldn't take that expression so literally.

Comment: "Obviously Kalidas thought of himself as the FATHER of the Goddess." -- really? Anything? @PradipGangopadhyay

Comment: Read the question again for the answer.